# SQL Server Adding one row to another but only for one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Probably best understood by the picture below.

[image: I have the table on the left but want the table on the right]. I want to add together any items that share a reference number **without** adding up the table number column. My SQL is of the form

```
SELECT

[Order Reference]
,[Item Price]
,[Table Number]

From Orders
```

I'm pretty sure I need to SELECT from a second SELECT that sums the items prices but I can't get the exact syntax for summing over the order reference without summing the table numbers also.

Edit :

I think I left out important info for the first answerers. And I clearly messed up the sample data. Many apologies. The table has other columns that I haven't included in my query so when I try a group by I still get multiple rows. I want to isolate the particular column and merge the rows disregarding any column that is different (I don't mind which data of the other columns is chosen)

So for clarity (hopefully) the table also has 20 other columns like discount yes or no which I basically want to ignore but which seem to prevent the rows from merging together from a simple group by clause.

[image]

Comment: How do we decide which `Table Number` is preserved? Is it the highest? (Before you answer "first", be clear that tables have *no* inherent ordering, and so if you say "first", you also have to say by what *criteria* we can determine the first, based on column values).

Comment: table number will always be the same for the same reference number so preserve any.

Comment: Your sample data contradicts you.

Comment: Oops so it does. Sorry, need to change that to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `SUM()` up the Items and `GROUP` your result `BY` your (desired unique) value(s).

```
SELECT [Order Reference],
       SUM(PRICE) as 'Items Total',           
       [Table Number] as 'Table Number'
FROM Orders
Group By [Order Reference], [Table Number]
```

Note:

When working with [aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql) such as `SUM`, `MAX` and others you have to group by every column you want to display in your `SELECT`.

Comment: [tag:sql-server] won't allow `TableNumber` in the `SELECT` clause without it being either a grouping column or contained in an aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

try this query to find your answer

```
SELECT Order_Reference, SUM(Item_Price) AS 'Total_Item', Table_Number 
FROM Your_Table_Name
GROUP BY Order_Reference,Table_Number 
ORDER BY Order_Reference ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to get expected result

```
SELECT ORDER_REFERENCE, SUM(ITEM_PRICE) AS ITEMS_TOTAL, TABLE_NUMBER FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY ORDER_REFERENCE, TABLE_NUMBER  ORDER BY TABLE_NUMBER;
```

Comment: This would still produce two `AT44T` rows based on the sample data.

Comment: In this case TABLE_NUMBER should be ignored else while grouping it gives two results

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Order By clause for the two column `OrderReference` and `TableNumber`.

You can use the below query but this will contradit the result table you have shown as the One `OrderReference` will produce two output since there `TableNumber` is different.

```
SELECT orderreference, 
       Sum(itemprice) AS ItemTotal, 
       tablenumber 
FROM   so_orders 
GROUP  BY orderreference, 
          tablenumber 
ORDER  BY orderreference
```